# Solve the equation $F(x,y) =2x^3 - 2y^3 + 3x^2y + 3y$ and define the stationary points

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

I am kind of lost as how to solve this question. I have to derive it first to get the stationary points by putting the derivative equation $=0 $, but here I have two variables, what do I do ?

$F (x,y) =2x^3 - 2y^3 + 3x^2y + 3y$?

Answer (score 0):

I got a maximum for $$(x,y)=(-1,1)$$ saddle points for $$(0,\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$
and a minimum for $$(1;-1)$$

Comment: Would you mind showing me the step by step procedure, to get there?

Comment: Im assuming you used partial derivatives , set the derivative functions to zero and solved it , but id like to compare with my notes

Answer (score 0):

- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=6x^2+6xy=6x(x+y)=0\Rightarrow x=0$ or $x=-y$
- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=-6y^2+3x^2+3=0$. If $x=0$ then $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, so $(0,\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$. If $x=-y$ then $(\pm 1,\mp 1)$.